# Generating gene signature for sample classification and survival analysis patient cohort

Tags: r, rna-seq

This is from this [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature20598)

The LSC17 score is calculated for each patient as a linear combination of GE of these 17 genes weighted by regression coefficients that were estimated from the training data as follows: `LSC17 score = (DNMT3B × 0.0874) + (ZBTB46 × −0.0347) + (NYNRIN × 0.00865) + (ARHGAP22 × −0.0138) + (LAPTM4B × 0.00582) + (MMRN1 × 0.0258) + (DPYSL3 × 0.0284) + (KIAA0125 × 0.0196) + (CDK6 × −0.0704) + (CPXM1 × −0.0258) + (SOCS2 × 0.0271) + (SMIM24 × −0.0226) + (EMP1 × 0.0146) + (NGFRAP1 × 0.0465) + (CD34 × 0.0338) + (AKR1C3 × −0.0402) + (GPR56 × 0.0501).` As above- and below-median scores in the training cohort were associated with adverse and favourable cytogenetic risk, respectively, a **median threshold** was used to discretize scores into high and low groups.

I'm unable to understand or apply the median threshold to create patient group specifically the R implementation here.

In order to address the problem my small dummy data-frame
This is my dummy data

```
set.seed(123)
nr1 = 20; nr2 = 8; nr3 = 6; nr = nr1 + nr2 + nr3
nc1 = 16; nc2 = 8; nc3 = 10; nc = nc1 + nc2 + nc3
mat = cbind(rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc1, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc1, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc1, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3)),
            rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc2, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc2, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc2, mean = 0,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3)),
            rbind(matrix(rnorm(nr1*nc3, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.5), nr = nr1),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr2*nc3, mean = 0.5, sd = 0.5), nr = nr2),
                  matrix(rnorm(nr3*nc3, mean = 1,   sd = 0.5), nr = nr3))
)
mat = mat[sample(nr, nr), sample(nc, nc)] # random shuffle rows and columns
rownames(mat) = paste0("gene", seq_len(nr))
colnames(mat) = paste0("LSC", seq_len(nc))
```

They have generated the LSC17 score by doing lasso,here in this case will create a dummy 5 gene score such as this

```
LSC5 score = (gene1 × 0.0874) + (gene6 × −0.0347) + (gene10 × 0.00865) + (gene22 × −0.0138) + (gene28× 0.00582)
```

**Now to generate or categorize the samples into above or below the median score.**

How to implement the above step in R which Im unable to do it?
One suggestion I received is this

```
 combined into a single variable when you make LSC17. After that, it's just quantile(LSC17,probs=c(0.3333,0.6666))
```

Which I unsuccessfully followed as I don't know how to implement it in the whole data frame.

Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated

I got an elegant solution which I asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/610125/using-multiple-genes-building-gene-signature-and-survival-analysis) If there are other ways in R to do this I would love to know